# Creating Computed Column based on another table column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

How to create a computed column based on the `Title nvarchar(max)` column of another table?

I want to make `Title` in table 1 a computed column from table2 based on `docId = DocId`. I keep trying to add it as computed column in SSMS and it won't let me.

Table1

```
AssetId  Title   DocId
========================
```

Table2

```
DocId  Title      
=========================
5      Disaster       
10     Recovery        
15     Pending
```

Comment: You can't create computed column using another table column.

Comment: can you explain what a computed column is? in term of values in varchar.

Comment: Why would you want that computed column to exist?. You want to not write the `JOIN`?

Comment: Are you trying to make a computed column based on another column in a different table?  That would fall under the topic of _view_.

Comment: Whilst a view is preferable, I suppose you could create a function to look at the other table, then use that in the definition of the computed column. Not very efficient though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create computed column using another table column. But you can define Table 1 as
AssetId, DocId and create view as you desired.

```
CREATE VIEW YouVIEW
AS
SELECT T1.AssetId, T1.DocId, T2.Title
FROM Table1 T1
    JOIN Table2 T2
       ON T1.DocId = T2.DocId
```

This is parametrized inline function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetValue (@DocId INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    (SELECT T1.AssetId, T1.DocId, T2.Title 
     FROM Table1 T1 
        JOIN Table2 T2 
           ON T1.DocId = T2.DocId 
     WHERE T1.DocID = @DocId
    )
GO
```

Comment: How would the function look?  The view is working, thanks for the view!

Comment: Why you want to use function. The view is most applicable for your problem.

Comment: [CREATE FUNCTION (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The definition of computed columns explicitly states that the columns must be in the same table ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)).

What you probably want is a view.

```
create view vw_table1 as
    select t.AssetId, d.Title, t.docid
    from table1 t left outer join
         table2 d
         on t.docid = d.docid
```